# Craft incredibly slow site performance

Tags: control-panel, cache, performance, eager-loading

I am experiencing incredibly slow site performance. This extends to loading the control panel (/dashboard, /login).

This only happens when I put the site on to my hosting, locally using MAMP it runs quickly.

I have done the following which are recommended in other posts:

- upped the `memory_limit` to `512M`
- used `(% cache globally using key 'entry-' ~ entry.id %}`
- used eager loading for image assets
- Disabled/enabled plugins

Can someone please help?

Comment: I'd do some performance profiling to see what's going on. Assuming it's Craft 3, this should help: https://nystudio107.com/blog/profiling-your-website-with-craft-cms-3s-debug-toolbar

Comment: Related: https://craftcms.com/support/why-is-my-site-slow

Comment: @andrew.welch it looks like this is the culprit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out this was the culprit. Craft was doing a deprecationerrors query (https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/2539).

Turning `devMode` to `false` fixed this.

Hope this helps someone...

[image]